# Why are there random lines of wooden planks going through my castle on my private Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It's kinda creepy now... First, an invisible fire block that nearly burned down a jungle, even though I couldn't put it out. Now, a strip of wooden planks spanning across several chunks... It's really starting to freak me out. What is it?

Comment: Can you post screenshots?

Comment: Can you check the server log and make sure no one else has l logged in to it?

Comment: This question probably has no definite answer and is out of the scope.

Comment: Pictures, please? Are you using the default texture pack?

If everything is right and good, then the obvious answer is: Herobrine

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are using a different texture pack that:
a) Is higher than 16x16
b) Modified

If you are using a higher resolution texture pack without patching Minecraft, blocks can sometimes be invisible, texture may be messed up, and other various things, such as what you mentioned above, occur.